# Basic PHPMailer SMTP configuration issue

Tags: phpmailer

I am trying to configure the PHPMailer for SMTP.

Here is my code:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $recipient_email = $_POST["eb_email_m"];
    $recipient_name = $_POST["eb_firstname"] . $_POST["eb_lastname"];
    $recipient_reference = $_POST["eb_reference_m"];

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->IsSMTP();                                    
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.strato.de';                      
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                       
    $mail->Port = 587;                                   
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                              
    $mail->Username = 'contact@vroum.biz';               
    $mail->Password = 'XXXXXXXXXX';                   
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            
    $mail->AddReplyTo("contact@vroum.biz", "VROUM GABON -- APPLI MOBILE");
    $mail->setFrom('contact@vroum.biz', 'VROUM GABON -- APPLI MOBILE');
    $mail->AddAddress($recipient_email);                  
    $mail->IsHTML(true);                                
    $mail->Subject = 'VROUM GABON - INSCRIPTION CONDUCTEUR';
    $mail->Body = 'Bonjour' . $recipient_name . ',<br/><br/>' .
                  'Votre paiement est en cours.<br/><br/>' .
                  'Votre numéro de référence:' . $recipient_reference . '<br/><br/>' .                                
                  'Dès que la transaction est effectuée, votre profil de conducteur<br/>' .
                  'sera mis en ligne et vous pourrez poster une offre de covoiturage.<br/>'  .
                  '<br/><br/>' .
                  '<b>QUESTIONS/CONTACT: Tél: +241 07371979 - email: service@suncomcocotiers.com<b/>' .
                  '<br/>' .
                  '<b>@2016 VROUM GABON</b><br/>'    .
                  '<b><a href="#">SUNCOM COCOTIERS</a></b>';

    $mail->AltBody = 'Le contenu du message email pour les clients non html';

    //send the message, check for errors
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "Message sent!";
    }
}
```

I looked closely at the example:

[https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/smtp.phps][1]

The three recipient variables ($recipient_email,$recipient_name, $recipient_reference) all have a sanitized value.

I don't know how to properly debug this as the PHP code moves on to the next PHP page and correctly populates the database with the form data.

Thanks in advance.

K.

Comment: So what's the problem? You say you're looking at that example, but you're using an old version, not the up to date one you pointed at. The script you have posted does not redirect, and it will display debug output and display any errors - so just run this script by itself, and show us the output.

Comment: The problem is that I receive no email and as I mentioned, even with the display debug output & errors commands on, the form action in the same file brings me to another page. I don't manage to interrupt the PHP script and don't see any error output. What is old about the PHPMailer version and example I am using ?

Comment: My mistake. The code works perfectly fine.